# Set hyperlinks to certain sections of the same picture? (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have certain parts of the same picture hyperlinked to different webpages
Is there a way I can do this with javascript coordinates or any other way?

Comment: You're looking for the HTML `MAP` tag.

Comment: Bear in mind that by using this method that you are not going to end up with a nice responsive, modern layout...

Comment: @athms Bear in mind your statement is correct if "this method" refers to using (large) images as a primary styling method. Maps themselves are not that slow, as far as I know.

Comment: @JanDvorak the `map` element is perfectly suited to the solution, I was just saying that the end result isn't particularly great in this day and age.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the HTML `MAP` tag, for example:

```
<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png"
    width="512" height="512" alt="Logo" usemap="#logomap"/>
<map name="logomap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,256,512"
      href="javascript:alert('left')" alt="Left">
  <area shape="rect" coords="256,0,512,512"
      href="javascript:alert('right')" alt="Right">
</map>
```

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dw8qd/) to try it out. Clicking on the left side of the image will show a Javascript alert that says `left`, on the right side it will show `right`.